# How to have Pipewire auto route Zoom to node other than sound card?

Tags: sound, pipewire

When using Zoom, Teams etc. I want to auto mute the mic when not talking to block background noise such as the keyboard. Carla with a gate plugin works well.

My question is: how to have Pipewire recognise Zoom / Teams or its input port & auto route it to take gated audio from Carla and not directly from the sound card capture port?

It seems that it should be possible to tell Pipewire the name of some app or node or stream, and have it auto link wherever I want it to go as soon as the app / node / stream appears in the pipewire graph. I think I see the possibility in the docs, but can't see how to actually do it. Brain bent seriously out of shape.

It will always be necessary to run a script to start all of the apps involved in this, but then I want Pipewire to recognise & connect everything together.

If someone can show me a method to achieve the auto routing, perhaps with an example, I can take it from there.

In the mean time, I have a working kludge adapted from these [scripts posted by one of the PW devs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire#PipeWire_native_patch_sets). After joining a Zoom or Teams meeting (so that required streams are established) I quickly type a short command to run a script that;

1. starts Carla & load the rack containing the gate plugin (whose levels I've previously configured);
2. starts meterbridge (why not?);
3. links everything together;

   - sound card capture > Carla input     # raw mic audio to Carla
   - Carla output > Zoom / Teams input;   # gated mic audio to Zoom / Teams
   - Z / T output > sound card playback   # so I can hear Zoom / Teams
   - Carla output > sound card playback   # so I can hear myself
   - Carla output > meterbridge           # check Carla output level peaks about -3dB
   - Z / T output > meterbridge           # so I can set my level like other participants

Happy to share if anyone wants the scripts.